# Need dynamic multipicklist code

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anyone furnish me with a small simple VF page that has one multi picklist field and an Apex class that does a query against a custom object to get a list of names and populates the field with them?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying right now. If I get close enough, I can post so I can get feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Contacts"
    leftOptions="{!allContacts}"
    rightLabel="Selected Contacts"
    rightOptions="{!selectedContacts}"
    size="14"
    width="150px"/>
```

It looks like this:
[image: Multi-picklist]

Read more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html

Also try this: https://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/custom-multi-select-picklist-field-in-visualforce/